# Gaussian: Error termination just before the calculation ends

Tags: density-functional-theory, gaussian, perovskites

I am trying to optimize a cluster based structure using DFT. However, just before the calculation ends the gaussian give me an error termination without even specifying the cause of this error

```
46 H 0.000000
47 H 2.379115 0.000000
Symmetry turned off by external request.
Stoichiometry      C16H22Br4C12CUN2(2)
Framework group    C1[(C16H22Br4C12CUN2)]
Deg. of freedom    135
Full point group   C1  NOp   1
Rotational constants (GHZ): 0.2369033    0.0272776   0.0265363


        EVOLUTION
IN THE BEGINNING GOD MADE MAN.
HE WORKED THE DIRT WITH HIS HANDS.
THEN GOD DECIDED TO GIVE MAN SCIENCE.
MAN SHOULD BE USEFUL (LIKE AN APPLIANCE.) 
BUT SOON MAN'S KNOWLEDGE GREW TOO GREAT, 
TO THE HEADING SCIENCE HE COULDN'T RELATE
SO GOD SAID "LETS HAVE DIFFERENT FIELDS, 
WE'LL DIVIDE THEM UP, SEE WHAT IT YIELDS."
ENTER PHYSICS, CHEMISTRY, BIO 
THEY SPRANG UP AROUND THE NILE.
BUT CHEMISTRY SURPASSED THE REST
FAR AND AWAY IT WAS THE BEST.
EXPERIMENT WAS GOD'S DECREE
EXPERIMENT DID CHEMISTS WITH LOTS OF GLEE
BUT SOON THEIR TESTS BEGAN TO BOG, 
THEY FOUND THEMSELVES DEEP IN A FOG.
"GIVE US SOME HELP" THEY CRIED TO GOD.
GOD LOOKED AROUND, THEN GAVE THE NOD.
ENTER EINSTEIN, HEISENBERG, BOHR, 
REACTION PATHS WERE CLEAR ONCE MORE.
WITH THEORISTS GOD SEND DIRECTION 
AND THEN HE STOPPED, HE'D MADE PERFECTION.
         - - THOMAS A. HOLME, 1981
Error termination request processed by link 9999.
Error termination via Lnkle in /opt/apps/gaussian/09b01/em64t/19999.exe at Fri Jan 27 11:06:54 2023.
Job cpu time: 0 days 0 hours 0 minutes 38.1 seconds.
File lengths (MBytes): RWF=  152 Int= 0 D2E= 0 Chk= 32 Scr=  8
```

Comment: Please replace this screenshot image with text in a `code` block, so that it's searchable and viewable on screen readers and browsers that don't load images!

Comment: Are there any errors printed earlier in the output? My memory of this is a bit hazy, but I seem to remember scf/geopts that ran out of steps will still continue on to print summary information before ending with error termination.

Comment: Can you include also the input? 
Are you using some sort of implicit solvation?